# How to make cmake to find local library in /usr/local/lib?

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, dynamic-linking

I have create simple library *testlib.c*:

```
char *reverse(char *string)
{
    int len = strlen(string);
    for (int i = 0; i < len / 2; i++)
    {
        char tmp = string[i];
        string[i] = string[len - 1 - i];
        string[len - 1 - i] = tmp;
    }
    return string;
}
```

Now created shared library:

```
cc -fPIC -shared -o libtest.so testlib.c -lc
sudo mv libtest.so /usr/local/lib
```

Now having this cmake project:

```
.
├── c1
│   └── main.cpp
└── CMakeLists.txt
```

*main.cpp*:

```
#include <iostream>

char *reverse(char*);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        puts(argv[1]);
        puts(reverse(argv[1]));
    }
}
```

and finally in *CMakeLists.txt*:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20.0)
project(c1)

add_executable(c1 c1/main.cpp)
include_directories(.)

find_library(TEST_LIBRARY
        NAMES test)
link_libraries(c1 TEST_LIBRARY)
```

I am getting link error:

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x3b): undefined reference to `reverse(char*)'
```

even with the `find_library` cmake command. So how to make cmake to find local library and link it?

Comment: Correct line which links the executable with the library is `target_link_libraries(c1 ${TEST_LIBRARY})`. See e.g. [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41909627/3440745).

Comment: Still getting link error, after changing it after the provided answer. Now the cmake is:

`set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /usr/local/lib)`
`find_library(TEST_LIB test)`
`link_libraries(c1 ${TEST_LIB})`

but still undefined reference

Comment: Please, read the other code **carefully**. The command is named `target_link_libraries`, not `link_libraries`.